# Why is my @Override of toString() method never called on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, overriding, tostring

It seems that my implementation of `toString()` method in an Activity is never called no matter what I do. I always get result from `java.lang.Object` (like `Ljava.lang.Object;@4059d6a8`) instead of "I was called!". I've read a bunch of articles and scanned through a lot of code and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Could someone please explain to me how do I override the method? This is my code:

```
public class OverrideTestActivity extends Activity {
    private int number = 27;
    private String[] items = { "MyFirstItem", "MySecondItem" };
    public Object[] stuff = { number, items };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        OverrideTest();
    }

    public void OverrideTest() {
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        result.setText(stuff.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I was called!";
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the `toString()` is called only on objects of type `OverrideTestActivity`.

Instead you are calling toString() on an array, which doesn't have such an implementation.

```
private int number = 27;
private String[] items = { "MyFirstItem", "MySecondItem" };
public Object[] stuff = { number, items };
```

If you did something like this

```
List<Object> stuff = Arrays.asList(27, "MyFirstItem", "MySecondItem");
stuff.toString();
```

You would find that it outputs a format that represents the contents of the List.  The format will have been determined by the `toString()` method on the List implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You are overriding the `toString()` method for the class `OverrideTestActivity` and calling `toString()` for the array of Objects: that's why you are getting the default implementation of the `Object` class.

Comment: I'll mark jkschneider's answer as accepted one as it actually solved my problem. Much appreciated though, thanks for clarrification!